# Do something at given time

Tags: android, android-studio

My app needs to do some work and then display notification at some given time in day (for example at 12:00). Is there some reliable way to do this?

I've heard about `WorkManager` and `AlarmManager`, bud I didn't find any working, up-to-date example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlarmManager didn't work for me, until I discovered, that you can't test it with the green play button in Android Studio. If you wan't to test, how the manager reacts when the app is killed, you need to start the app by clicking on it on your phone

Answer (score 0):

Work manager is about deferrable work. To do something at an exact time, use AlarmManager API.

As for up-to-date example, just read the documentation, rather than trying out random code from stackoverflow:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#set